# Running Postgres as Launch Daemon

Tags: launchd, postgresql, daemons

I am working on setting up a psql server and would therefore like postgres to run whenever the computer is on, regardless of whether I'm logged it. (The machine is running OS X Yosemite.) I set up a launch daemon to do this, but it doesn't work. `syslog` gives the following error messages:

```
Jul 14 17:43:01 user@server sudo[276]:     jaia : TTY=ttys000 ; 
PWD=/Users/jaia ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/homeb
rew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Jul 14 17:44:35 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql): T
his service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Jul 14 17:44:44 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql): S
ervice only ran for 9 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Jul 14 17:44:45 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql): S
ervice only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

After that, the last message repeats indefinitely.

Here's my .plist file. The reason for `sudo -u _postgres` is that postgres can't run as root, which launch daemons do by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sudo</string>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>_postgres</string>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
    <string>start</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>_postgres</string>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

MORE INFORMATION: Loading the job manually via ssh gives the ungrammatical error message "Could not find domain for". Loading it on the machine itself gives "/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: File exists".

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the `sudo`, `-u` and `_postgres` in `ProgramArguments`. launchd takes care of this with the `UserName` key.

Comment: I made the change and while I'm not getting the "postgresql can't run as root" message, it's still not launching.

Comment: What does `launchctl` report? What's in `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`?

Comment: There's nothing new in the postgres log. How do I check what `launchctl` is reporting?

Comment: You may want to check out the 'Troubleshooting' section of this launchd [tutorial](http://launchd.info). It explains how to start a job and what to do if it does not work

Comment: Loading the job manually via ssh gives the error message "Could not find domain for". That's apparently common with ssh. I'll try again when I can get into the room.

Comment: Loading the job in person gives "/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: File exists".

Comment: Which command do you use?

Comment: `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` (That's from memory, but I think it's what I did.)